# Updating to PCL 1.7 in ROS Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been working to install the latest version of PCL 1.7 in ROS so I can run the correspondence tutorial [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php#correspondence-grouping)

I've tried installing the latest version 1.6 using,
apt-get install ros-fuerte-perception-pcl-fuerte-unstable

Although, this is just an update to PCL 1.6 which doesn't have the necessary header file board.h along with a few others.

I saw a similar post at [this](http://www.pcl-users.org/Correspondence-Grouping-Tutorial-ROS-td4021994.html) forum posting.  But it looks as though the svn link has expired for pcl-trunk that was references,

svn co http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable/

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44821/updating-to-pcl-1.7-in-ros-fuerte/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2012-09-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl17 with some further information.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Areeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/5413/areeb/) on 2013-08-02**:
Hi followed your tutorial but while checking out with svn i got this error

areeb@ubuntu:~$ sudo svn co https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl
C pcl/tags
svn: Directory 'pcl/trunk' is missing
svn: Directory 'pcl/trunk' is missing

Please Help me thanx

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-08-02**:
this is a git repository, not svn, but you can find the right command on that wiki page: git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git -b fuerte-unstable-devel fuerte-unstable-devel

**Comment by [Areeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/5413/areeb/) on 2013-08-03**:
its giving this error now..   "/pcl_trunk" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt". I have checked it manually and yes its not present.. I am building pcl17 btw... Thanx and the full path is like this " "/home/areeb/fuerte-unstable-devel/pcl17/build/pcl_trunk""

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-08-04**:
I just tested the script, it works fine. You should completely delete the folder fuerte-unstable-devel. Then try it again. First "git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git -b fuerte-unstable-devel fuerte-unstable-devel", then "rosmake pcl17".

**Comment by [Areeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/5413/areeb/) on 2013-08-05**:
Thanks. I have successfully configured it. Now i am trying to run a tutorial of main_ground_base_people_detection but ended with error "The type 'pcl17::visualization::PointCloudColorHandler' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'pcl17::visualization::PointCloudColorHandler::getColor' "

**Comment by [Areeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/5413/areeb/) on 2013-08-05**:
any idea? by the way thanks alot for your help. Bless you =)

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-08-05**:
Maybe you can find help here: http://www.pcl-users.org/

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-24**:
@Areeb im working exactly in the same thing im getting problems with the pcl17 and i want to run to same tutorial did you make it work after all? I would really appreciate any help

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-24**:
@MichaelKorn when i do the rosmake pcl 17 i get the following error, do you know why?
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pcl17']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/Cristobal/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130924-092134
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pcl17'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['pcl17']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-09-25**:
did you change the folder name?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-25**:
@MichaelKorn thanks that was one problem, but now that i was able to rosmake , when i run a tutorial it says that my version is stil 1.5 , do you why this happens?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-09-25**:
pcl17 has its own Namespace. You should have both versions.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-25**:
@MichaelKorn thanks i though that two but im unable to make it work, im trying to do this tutorial
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection.php
and when i write the CMakeLists.txt i put the following line
find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)
and when i run it says that it only finds the 1.5 version , of you understand why? or should i change something of the CMakeLists.txt?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-09-25**:
checkout with SVN http://fsstud.is.uni-due.de/svn/ros/is/kinfu/ r264. Not newer! You will find  in manifest.xml.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-25**:
@MichaelKorn cant manage to get to the 264 , it sends me directly to the 276??

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-09-25**:
do it local: svn checkout http://fsstud.is.uni-due.de/svn/ros/is/kinfu/ -r264

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-26**:
@MichaelKorn Im a little confused, in the kinfu i have the manifest and a CMakeLists.txt, but for my tutorial i only have the CMake so i dont know what to do with the  in manifest.xml.  I have to add it to the main_ground_based_people_detection.cpp??

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-10-11**:
@MichaelKorn this link that you provided with the kinfu, this is a simplified version of the kinfu_app? I'm working on my own version of refactored kinfu_app that would enable me to usi it wit a pmd Camboard nano / miniTOF Camera ...

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-12**:
this is a ros wrapper for  kinfu, it is derived from kinfu_app. Essentially the GUI elements are replaced by ROS messages.

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-10-13**:
Ok. Is it possbile to tweak it to use it not only with Kinect?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-13**:
yes, it is possible, but you have to adapt KinFu. At least the right focal length muss be considered.

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-10-13**:
Could you specify a bit more in detail? I've started a new thread : http://answers.ros.org/question/90431/kinfu-with-pmd-camboard-nano/ I'm really trying to fix this problem.

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-10-13**:
I now that I have to map the outputs of the PMD camera, and also that there is a ROS package for this. "focal length" - is this a parameter of kinfu?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-14**:
@MichaelKorn my cmkaelist is as follows.--cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(ground_based_rgbd_people_detector)
find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (ground_based_rgbd_people_detector MACOSX_BUNDLE src/main_ground_based_people_detection.cpp)
target_link_libraries (ground_based_rgbd_people_detector ${PCL_LIBRARIES})

how do i change the find package(pcl 1.7) to direct it to pcl17 so it works? thanks because now it says i only have pcl 1.5

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-14**:
You don't need spacial changes in your CMakeLists.txt! You only need pcl17 in your manifest.xml. And use also the new namespace (pcl17::)

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-14**:
@MichaelKorn
i created a new package depending on pcl17



ihave the three in my manifest and still cant manage to create the exe or make the program work.  The cmake is standard due to it was created when the pkg was created and it does no create the exe. any ideas

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-14**:
you still need add_executable(...).  Do you get a error message?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-14**:
Yes i have the add_exe but still. I have the following error,note: 'boost::system::system_category()' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1: but ive been unable to solve it

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-14**:
Did you link it? Add after add_executable(..): target_link_libraries(YOUR_PROGRAM boost_system .....)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/44136/how-to-solve-pclfeaturesboardh-not-found/?answer=44215#post-id-44215) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/36837/how-to-use-current-experimental-pcl-together-with-ros-fuerte/) post.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2012-10-01**:
Unfortunately this doesn't help me out much.  I've seen these posts and I'm finding that there is a svn co http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable/ but only for pcl16.  The header file that the 3D Object recognition tutorial needs in in pcl17.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I believe I figured out the update for using pcl17.

change directories to your ROS_PACAKGE_PATH roscd then use,

svn co http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17

svn co http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17_ros

once you have these checked out change folders and do rosmake on each pcl17 and pcl17_ros.  Side note, it took a while to run rosmake on pcl17 so make sure you give it enough time.

If you are planning to use these in your package for say a pcl tutorial you have to change your 'manifest.xml' from,

to,

Once you've done this make sure to update your references to pcl:: in your project to pcl17::

I am still working on getting the correspondence tutorial to work,
but I have been getting solutions to errors [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/using-pcl17-and-pcl17-ros-td4022695.html#a4022714)

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2012-10-10**:
a patch has been pushed in a recent version of ROS pcl 1.7 package.  So the above method should work for anyone trying to install pcl 1.7, I have finally been able to get the correspondence tutorial to work! :u)

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-06-24**:
I try you're version and come back if it works. The other suggestions did not work for me. So compiling from source and installing that one. (The ones mentioned under this post. Also the documentation is a bit less in case an error happens)

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-06-25**:
I could compile the package but I could not yet link it to another project. Maybe some suggestions? In the cmake file everything works fine.

**Comment by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on 2013-06-25**:
Linking the libraries: target_link_libraries(minitof_listener pcl17_features pcl17_io pcl17_2d pcl17_people pcl17_kdtree pcl17_registration pcl17_recognition pcl17_tracking pcl17_stereo pcl17_filters pcl17_common pcl17_visualization pcl17_octree pcl17_sample_consensus ... etc. )

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-24**:
@ncr7 run rosmake on pcl17 is taking for ever more than 3000 s is this normal?? how long should it take?

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2013-09-24**:
Yes, it takes awhile to build.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-09-25**:
It depends on your configuration and your computer. 50 minutes can be ok. A typical mistake is to use too many job if you don't have enough memory and the swap muss be used.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-26**:
@MichaelKorn @ncr7
After a while it took 4 hr but it got the job done thanks, the thing is that i only did rosmake on pcl17 and not on pcl17_ros, whats the difference between this two? because right now i can use programs from pcl17 with no problems

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-09-26**:
pcl17 is just the pcl, no ROS code! pcl17_ros contain ros code, based on the pcl.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-03**:
@MichaelKorn @ncr7 im having a little problem trying to use some code of the pcl17, specifically the detection of people, with ROS.  Right now i need to publish the distance i get from getDistance() but im unable to accomplish it.  Do you have any idea how to do it or experience working this package with ROS?

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2013-10-03**:
I have used pcl17, but haven't tried detection of people yet.  Sounds like an interesting thing to get working though, if I get time I'll try testing it.  CarolineQ might have some answers though, http://answers.ros.org/question/61607/pcl-people-detector-problem/

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-08**:
@MichaelKorn @ncr7  as i said im working on pcl17 and specifically on main_ground_based_people_detection.cpp , the thing is i dont know how to compile the new code or changes to the code without doing rosmake to everything, is the a way to compile the changes without doing the whole rosmake

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-08**:
the make system should check the timestamp of all involved files, but compile only changed files (recursively).

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-08**:
@MichaelKorn  thanks i did it and it did not take as long, but when i change the main_ground_based_people_detection.cpp and run the rosmake the exe is not changed? do you know why?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-09**:
pcl17 is not foreseen to make changes of the source code. But it should work if you remove the file "installed" before make.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-10**:
@MichaelKorn thanks it worked, but now as i expected it said there was a failure, but nothing more so i cant see which is the problem in the code , any ideas?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-10-10**:
maybe make it directly: roscd pcl17 && cd build/pcl_trunk/build && make

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-10**:
@MichaelKorn @ncr7 ok thanks, the error i get is "undefined reference to `ros::init" even though i included ros/ros.h , any ideas why?

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2013-10-11**:
might be a linking issue, try adding these lines to your cmake.
include_directories(/usr/include/vtk-5.8)
target_link_libraries(<your_executable_node> ${PCL_LIBRARIES} boost_system libvtkCommon.so libvtkFiltering.so libvtkRendering.so)

Also, maybe check your depends packages in your manifest.xml.